# Ambiguous use of subscript error only on real device

Tags: arrays, json, swift, subscript

When I try to run the code below on my iPhone, I get the following error

```
rrr.swift:356:72: Ambiguous use of 'subscript'
```

The strange thing is it happens only when I want to run the app on the phone, on the simulator however it works fine.

There are 3 lines which cause the error where. I noted them below in the code in capital letters.
I try to access properties in an array inside the JSON array, I suspect Im doing it the wrong way but have no idea how to fix it.

How can these properties be retrieved without the subscript error?

```
 self.restApi.getSchoolDetails(schoolId) {responseObject, error in
        // use responseObject and error here

         self.schoolDetailsCollection = NSDictionary(dictionary: responseObject! as! [String : AnyObject])
         print(self.schoolDetailsCollection)

        if let response = responseObject as? NSDictionary {
           //parse the response object
            self.schoolDetailsList = (response as? NSDictionary)!

            //assigning all values to shareData class
            self.shareData.sco_id = response["result"]!["sco_id"] as!NSInteger
            self.shareData.address = response["result"]!["address"] as!String
            self.shareData.name = response["result"]!["name"] as! String
            print("school name")
            print(self.shareData.name)
            self.shareData.intro = response["result"]!["intro"] as! String
           self.shareData.sell_point = response["result"]!["sell_point"] as! String
            self.shareData.city = response["result"]!["city"] as! String
            self.shareData.cou_id = response["result"]!["cou_id"] as! String

            //get images from the nested array in the json array
            /THESE THREE LINES CAUSE THE ERROR SUBSRCIPT
             self.shareData.image1 = response["result"]!["images"][0]! as! String
            self.shareData.image2 = response["result"]!["images"]![1] as! String
            self.shareData.image3 = response["result"]!["images"]![2] as! String

            print(self.shareData.image1)
            print(self.shareData.image2)
            print(self.shareData.image3)



            //open next controller after all info has been set correctly
            //info is being passed by Singleton class Sharedata
            if let COBezierDemoViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("COBezierDemoViewController") as? COBezierDemoViewController {
                self.presentViewController(COBezierDemoViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        }

    }

}
```

The JSON file:

```
{
result =     {
    address = "223 Vincent St, West Perth WA 6005, Australia";
    city = Perth;
    "cou_id" = AU;
    "cur_id" = "";
    environment = R;
    financed = "<null>";
    images =         (
        "Phoenix_Academy_1.jpeg",
        "Phoenix_Academy_3.jpeg",
        "Phoenix_Academy_2.jpeg"
    );
    intro = "Our language school in Perth has a modern campus and a spacious garden. The language school is located 10 minutes north from the city center. You can reach the city center and the famous bea
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you hint that error in this line:

```
 self.shareData.image1 = response["result"]!["images"][0]! as! String
```

**Error:**

Error is `[0]` subscript which you are implementing in AnyObject.

```
response["result"]!["images"] // this is returning Optional<AnyObject> which do not have subscript option.
```

Correct way should be this:

1. Downcast `AnyObject as? [String]` // this will either return `nil` or an Optional `Array<String?>` where `String` is image name.

> Without downcasting, you will get **error: Ambiguous use of subscript.**

```
    let images  = response["result"]? ["images"] as? [String]
    images?.flatMap({ $0 }).forEach {
    print($0) // Phoenix_Academy_1.jpeg, Phoenix_Academy_3.jpeg, Phoenix_Academy_2.jpeg
   }
```

Comment: Thx a lot. works well and helps to understand me better